# Python Multiprocessing - 'map_async' RunTimeError issue handling

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, multiprocessing, runtime-error, python-multiprocessing

Here is a sample code which I'm running.

```
def function(elem):
    var1 = elem[0]
    var2 = elem[1]
    length = nx.shortest_path_length(G, source=var1, target=var2)
    return length

p = mp.Pool(processes=4)
results = p.map_async(function, iterable=elements)
track_job(results)
p.close()
p.join()
```

The error which I'm facing is -

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:                    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 192, in accepter
    t.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 852, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

Post this error entire process is halted/paused.

Two Questions:

1. Is this issue at the hardware level? Or can this be avoided?
2. How to handle this error, so that the other processes are still running? Also retry the faulty process?

TIA

Comment: Is this the complete code? Are you starting your script via  a main thread ?

Comment: This is not the complete code. Few non trivial parts are missing e.g. generating graph `G` with `networkx`, imports etc. Also assume the `mp.Pool` till the end part in under the `main()` function of the main thread.

Comment: Are there many threads which is created in your app, may be out of this context as well ? Some hints to lookup would be - What is your `ulimit` setting, and are there more threads in your app already running. If thread count is already ~ulimit that could be a problem.

Comment: thread count is `(cpu core count - 1)` for my i7 machine,it's running in 7 threads.

Comment: Please update your example code - even after adding import netwrokx as nx and import multiprocessing as mp, it still errors out on iterable=elements.  So you are likely missing something that would help others to help you.

Comment: BTW if it can't start a new thread chances are you've already used up the maximum threads on your machine.  Try dropping the number of threads.  Or do this to find out how many you actually have first: `from os import cpu_count` then `cpu_count()*5` should tell you your system limits.  That is unless you run our of RAM first.

Answer (score 1):

I typically do stuff like this, maybe it will work for you:

```
import psutil
p = mp.Pool(psutil.cpu_count(logical=False))
with Pool((psutil.cpu_count()-1) or 1) as p:
    try:
        results = [r for r in p.map_async(function, elements)]
    except Exception as e1:
        print(f'{e1}')
    finally:
        p.close()
        p.join()
```

For the track_job(results), you may want to multiprocess that as well depending on what it's doing.

The `try` / `except` / `finally` error handling could be used to help your program continue when it hits any exception as well, using Exception as the base exception case.